# Class *Factory does not exist when get data to show on frontend

Tags: magento2.3.3, resource-model, factory

I'm trying to get data from my custom table and show it to frontend.

I followed to this tutorial: https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/how-to-create-model-resource-model-and-collection-in-magento-2-400

Here is my code:

app/code/HaoNMN/Museinc/Model/SampleTable.php:

```
<?php
namespace HaoNMN\Museinc\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class SampleTable extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable');
    }
}
```

app/code/HaoNMN/Museinc/Model/ResourseModel/SampleTable.php:

```
<?php
namespace HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class SampleTable extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('museinc_sampletable', 'id');
    }
}
```

app/code/HaoNMN/Museinc/Model/ResourseModel/SampleTable/Collection.php:

```
<?php
namespace HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\SampleTable',
            'HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable'
        );
    }
}
```

app/code/HaoNMN/Museinc/Controller/Index/Index.php:

```
<?php
namespace HaoNMN\Museinc\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\SampleFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_modelFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param NewsFactory $modelNewsFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SampleFactory $modelFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $sampleModel = $this->_modelFactory->create();

        $item = $sampleModel->load(1);
        var_dump($item->getData());

        $data = $sampleModel->getCollection();
        var_dump($data->getData());
    }
}
```

And final is my route:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="museinc" frontName="museinc">
            <module name="HaoNMN_Museinc"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

But when I access my url: http://localhost/magentoCE233/museinc/index/index, it got error like this:

[image]

I search some post in here and someone said that this is solved by run command php bin/magento setup:di:compile. But when I run, it showed this error:

[image]

Can you tell me what wrong did I do?

Comment: Can you double check that when you reference `ResourseModel` in the file names you actually mean `ResourceModel`?

Comment: Try `use HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\SampleTableFactory;` in your controller and check it.

Comment: I fixed in controller but still got error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentoCE233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Check your `ResourceModel` folder name. You write in question is `ResourseModel`.

Comment: I agree with @DhadukMitesh you should check your folder name

Answer (score 0):

> Your Model class is `SampleTable` and you're adding `SampleFactory` in
>   construct. I don't know if that's a typo error but it should be
>   `SampleTableFactory`.

**After Changes Run these commands**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

**That should resolve the problem.**

Comment: I fixed like you said. I change SampleFactory to SampleTableFactory, and check permission also. Then my command setup:di:compile run ok, but when I access my url, it's still got error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HaoNMN\Museinc\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentoCE233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0

Comment: can you show your `di.xml`?

Comment: It's so long. I will give you a google drive link instead: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lzob2bYh6u8bIzp6kO0HC5kvn6EepG07

Comment: I just want to make sure that you have defined the ResourceModel collection to `di.xml`

Comment: How should I define it?

Comment: `<virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">your_table_name</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\SampleTable</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>`

Comment: No need to define in di.xml. @Tomato

Answer (score 0):

Have you check owner permission ?

Comment: Yes, it's full control

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use this in a comment.

Comment: He doesn't have enough reputation to comment @DhadukMitesh

Comment: But this is not an answer. And community disallow this.

Answer (score 0):

The error says clearly that your directory permission are not right.

For a quick fix just run:chmod 777 -R $pathToYourFolderWithMagentoProject

But I don't recommend it cus it's not a good practice, just do it for a quick check.
You could learn about file permissions, it's not that hard.

For a detailed guide please refer how to set the file permissions from the official guide.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Btw

Each time you change something in the constructor:

```
 public function __construct(
    EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    Logger $logger,
    FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null
) {
    parent::__construct($entityFactory);
    $this->_fetchStrategy = $fetchStrategy;
    if ($connection !== null) {
        $this->setConnection($connection);
    }
    $this->_logger = $logger;
}
```

You need to clear the related files under the directory:

```
var/generated
```

Because Magento 2 generates the code and puts it there.
This is because of dependency injection.

If you are running the app in the developer mode then the deletion of the files under var/generated is enough.

Alternatively you can use this commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Setup upgrade does wipe out everything from the var/generated and some additional directories.

or use

```
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

this will recompile all your classes :)

Hope this helps you understand a bit :)

Ps.
Folder Naming is not correct, please fix the naming